# In MySQL, how do I find a result in the database that is contained in a longer string I am matching against?

Tags: mysql, sql, match

I have the following string I need to pass up to a MySQL DB:

```
TURNER SERIES TREA @treavturnerL @tvturner
```

I have the following rows returned for the query `SELECT name FROM player`:

```
Babe Ruth
Ken Griffey Jr.
Trea Turner
Hank Aaron 
Brandon Crawford
```

How can I create a query (or stored procedure) of some kind that will return `Trea Turner`, as his name is contained in the original string?

Comment: See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kz9E7EvqXZBQ81uzM92tDN/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer is a full text index, where you can use `match` -- as Strawberry suggests in the comment.

You can also do this with regular expressions.  If you wanted *any* match you can use a trick with regular expressions:  simply replace the spaces with `|`:

```
where p.player regexp replace('TURNER SERIES TREA @treavturnerL @tvturner', ' ', '|')
```

If you want *all* "words" in the player's name to match, you can replace each word using `regexp_replace()`.  If nothing but spaces are left, you have a match:

```
where trim(regexp_replace(p.player, replace('TURNER SERIES TREA @treavturnerL @tvturner', ' ', '|'), '')) = ''
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c01de671b16f8b681903fc8c06561104) is a db<>fiddle.